# What is the difference of '2' and "2" in C++

Tags: c++

I have problem to understand '2' and "2".I  know '2' is char while "2" is char* ,but what confused me is that if I do this:

```
String input = "123";
int number = input[1]; //extract 2 from input
```

but it gives me that number equals to 50.How can it convert "2" to 50? It is what i confuse about. Anybody know why? thanks!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: You have to have some numerical value that indicates the text symbol '2'. 50 is as good as any.

Comment: @Theolodis He just does not have idea about char to int casting and ASCII conversion, otherwise it's a legit question for a beginner.

Comment: Brace yourselves, here come 10000 different answers for a question that shouldn't need explaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'2'` is a character literal. It occupies one byte and its internal ASCII code is 50. So in this statement

```
int number = input[1];
```

the value of character `input[1]` is assigned to number.

Consider for example

```
char c = '2';

std::cout << ( int )c << std::endl;
```

`"2"` is a string literal. It has type `const char[2]` because it includes the terminating zero.

You may not write

```
char c = "2";
```

But you may write

```
char c = "2"[0];
std::cout << ( int )c << std::endl;
```

and you will get the same result as above.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `input[1]` you are extracting the second char of input string. Which in this case is `'2'`. Then you are casting this char to an int variable which results in ASCII conversion of character `'2'`. The number 50 is the conversion of ASCII character `'2'`

Answer (score 0):

What your code does, it extracts second element in string, which is char '2' and implicitly casts it to integer. The result is an ASCII code for character '2' which is value of 50.

Answer (score 0):

Machines don't know about human concepts like "S", "4", "red", "small". They only know about numbers and therefore all of these concepts must be represented as a number. When engineers started to move human concepts to machines world they need to assign a standard number to them. For example, number 0 was used for representing the end of a string buffer. Number 10 was used for representing a line feed character, which makes a text break in several lines. The human concept "4" (rather, its graphical representation) was assigned number 50. All these assigments of numbers to graphical symbols are known as [ASCII](http://www.ascii-code.com/) table.

Your code, then, is getting the numerical representation of symbol "4", which is 50.